# Can't test if method was called when using delayed_job 'delay' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, mocha.js, testunit

I use Mocha, Test::Unit and delayed_job and wanted to test whether mailer method has been executed, like this:

```
  test "should send info about paid payment" do
    payment = Payment.new :contractor_name => "notempty", :address => "notempty"

    UserMailer.expects(:send_payment_info)

    payment.set_paid!

  end


  # model method
  def set_paid!
    self.status = 'paid'
    self.paid_at = Date.today
    self.save!

    UserMailer.delay.send_payment_info self
  end
```

Without using delay method test works as expected, but with it (and I have Delayed::Worker.delay_jobs = !Rails.env.test? in initializer config) I get:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass
>   app/models/payment.rb:33:in`set_paid!'
>       test/unit/payment_test.rb:50:in `test_should_send_info_about_paid_payment'

And I have no clue how to fix this? Maybe I should moch UserMailer differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such workaround helped:

```
UserMailer.stubs(:delay).returns UserMailer
UserMailer.expects(:send_payment_info)
```

Don't know if it's the legit way to go, but it works